# Converting a Dataframe to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Dataframe in CSV format as shown in the picture.

[image]

I want to convert it into a dictionary such that rows are key and values are also corresponding row.

for this, I used the code:-

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

match_pairs = pd.read_csv('data_d.csv',usecols=['Object','Pairs'])
match_pairs['Pairs'] = match_pairs['Pairs'].apply(literal_eval)
dict = match_pairs.transpose()
dict.to_dict()
print(dict['a'])
```

When I imported the dataframe in match_pairs, the Pairs column got imported as a string rather than a list. therefore I used **`literal_eval()`** to get the structure of data.

Further, **`.to_dict()`** func converts column as a key. Therefore I transposed the data and then used the **`.to_dict()`** func.

but unfortunately, I am not able to get the key-value pairs as I require.
I wanted that for **`print(dict['a'])`**, i get the value as **`['d','e','f']`**.

Kindly, help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First dont use `dict` for variable name, because builten, python code word.

Create `Series` and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
match_pairs = pd.read_csv('data_d.csv',usecols=['Object','Pairs'])
match_pairs['Pairs'] = match_pairs['Pairs'].apply(literal_eval)

d = match_pairs.set_index('Object')['Pairs'].to_dict()
```

Or use `zip` with `dict`:

```
#reset builtin if used like variable
#import builtins
#dict = builtins.dict
d = dict(zip(match_pairs['Object'], match_pairs['Pairs']))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. IT worked.
I was stuck in it for a long time.